# Why is the virtual address not 4KiB-aligned when its physical address is aligned to 4KiB?

Tags: kernel, memory

Briefly, I have a **physical address** inside kernel (9,932,111,872 or `0x250000000`), which is apparently **aligned to 4KiB** (page size). When I use the kernel `__va()` function to get the **kernel virtual address**, I got something like `0xf570660f` (different on each boot), which is **not aligned to 4KiB**.

I'm on a 64bit system so there's no HIGHMEM, and I thought that due to the liner memory model, a virtual address of an 4KiB-aligned physical address should also be 4KiB-aligned. Did I miss something? Shouldn't the virtual address be `phys_addr + PAGE_OFFSET`? Or is it the influence of the sparsemem? But maybe it should also be 4KiB-aligned?

Here are more details:

My workground is on a x86 64bit QEMU VM. I'm trying to use a PMEM in `DEV-DAX` mode as a normal memory. I can get the physical start address of it (`0x250000000`), which has been confirmed to be right. Then I need to transfer it to the virtual address in kernel space so that I can use it as I need. Here's some code:

```C
static long nvpc_map_whole_dev(struct dax_device *dax_dev, void **kaddr, pfn_t *pfn)
{
    // get the device
    struct dev_dax_nvpc *dax_nvpc = (struct dev_dax_nvpc *)dax_get_private(dax_dev);
    
    // get the virtual address and the pfn_t
    *kaddr = __va(dax_nvpc->phys_start);
    *pfn = phys_to_pfn_t(dax_nvpc->phys_start, PFN_MAP);
    
    pr_info("[NVPC DEBUG]: paddr %#llx kaddr %p pfn %lu\n", dax_nvpc->phys_start, *kaddr, pfn_t_to_pfn(*pfn));
    pr_info("[NVPC DEBUG]: kaddr-paddr %#llx\n", __pa(*kaddr));
    return PHYS_PFN(dax_nvpc->size);
}
```

And here's the result I got:

[image]

Shown in the marked line, the `paddr` `dax_nvpc->phys_start`, and the `pfn`, are both right. But the `kaddr` (virtual address) is confusing to me. Then when I transfer the `kaddr` back to physical address (the next output line), the result turns to be right.

What's more, I can do any operation on the memory from `kaddr` to `kaddr + dax_nvpc->size`, there's no page fault.

Could anyone tell me why is the virtual address is not 4KiB-aligned? Am I being a fool on somewhere? Further, can I do something to make sure that the virtual address is also aligned to a page?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The reason is the `%p` in `printk`. When I change `%p` to `%#llx` for a quick check, the output of kernel address becomes 4KB-aligned as expected.

The reason can be found here: [Kernel Doc: printk-formats pointer-types](https://docs.kernel.org/core-api/printk-formats.html#pointer-types). `%p` inside printk will print a hashed pointer address to prevent leaking kernel information. That's why the pointer seems weird. If you want to check the real virtual address just use `%px`, or add `no_hash_pointers` to the boot parameter. Refer to the link for more usage.